# Android DataStore: Calling Context.createDataStore from Java

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement the new typed DataStore API in Java and I'm having some issues. All the documentation seems to be in Kotlin only and trying to create a new data store is not as straight forward from the Java side it seems.

Calling `DataStoreFactoryKt.createDataStore()` from Java requires me to provide all the arguments including the ones with default values in the Kotlin implementation. There doesnt seem to be any `@JvmOverloads` annotation for that function, resulting in my predicament.

```
fun <T> Context.createDataStore(
    fileName: String,
    serializer: Serializer<T>,
    corruptionHandler: ReplaceFileCorruptionHandler<T>? = null,
    migrations: List<DataMigration<T>> = listOf(),
    scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())
): DataStore<T> =
    DataStoreFactory.create(
        produceFile = { File(this.filesDir, "datastore/$fileName") },
        serializer = serializer,
        corruptionHandler = corruptionHandler,
        migrations = migrations,
        scope = scope
)
```

What's the better way around this, if there is any? Or is the Data Store api simple designed to be used with Kotlin only? I have no idea how I would go about providing a `CoroutineScope` argument from Java.

Comment: The same issue happens from Kotlin client side, there is no default value for the Serializer, but the docs tell you that you can instantiate a DataStore<Preferences> just by supplying a file name. I think something is wrong here :(

Answer (score 14):

After updating dataStore dependency to '1.0.0-alpha08' as below.

```
// DataStore
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0-alpha08"
```

You can have preferences implementation as follow:

```
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("app_preferences")
```

After that if you like create some preference key:

```
private object Keys {
    val HIDE_VISITED = booleanPreferencesKey("hide_visited")
}
```

other options can be **string**PreferencesKey, **int**PreferencesKey, etc.

Saving value example:

```
context.dataStore.edit { prefs -> prefs[Keys.HIDE_VISITED] = hideVisited }
```

Reading saved value example:

```
val hideVisited = preferences[Keys.HIDE_VISITED] ?: false
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add to your Grade build file the dependency for DataStore **preferences**:

```
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0-alpha04"
```

and not the one for Types, that way you will be able to resolve the `androidx.datastore.preferences.Context.createDataStore` method that you are expecting:

```
public fun Context.createDataStore(
    name: String,
    corruptionHandler: ReplaceFileCorruptionHandler<Preferences>? = null,
    migrations: List<DataMigration<Preferences>> = listOf(),
    scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())
): DataStore<Preferences> =
    PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(
        corruptionHandler = corruptionHandler,
        migrations = migrations,
        scope = scope
    ) {
        File(this.filesDir, "datastore/$name.preferences_pb")
    }
```

Comment: This is not a solution. He cannot keep on using the older version of `DataStore`. A better solution would be to explain how to use the newer versions.

Comment: This answer explains that it's required to add another dependency, without specifying its version. I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use proto dataStore from version 1.0.0-beta01, you can:

```
implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-core:1.0.0-beta01")
```

initialize with Data Store Factory

```
      val data: DataStore<SomeMessage> = DataStoreFactory.create(
        serializer = SessionSerializer, // your Serializer
        corruptionHandler = null,
        migrations = emptyList(),
        scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job())
```

And continue as before

```
      data.updateData {
            it.toBuilder().setAddress("address").build()
        }

      data.collect { ChargingSession ->
                ChargingSession.address
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is only valid for dependency version `1.0.0-alpha08` and above

@Ercan approach is correct but requires `context` every time we need access to the dataStore.

Below is a better approach for the same.

```
private val Context._dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(APP_PREFERENCES)

private val dataStore : DataStore<Preferences> = context._dataStore

companion object {
    const val APP_PREFERENCES = "app_preferences"
}
```

reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173726702